# How to combine array values?

Tags: php

I am about to give up. I knwo it is dman simple but...
Here is what I have:

```
$stuff =     Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 0.5 ) Array ( [0] => 0.5 )
```

I need a sum the values (so 1 + 0.5 + 0.5) to a string?
what on Earth should I do? is there **non-recursive** way of doing so (like **array_sum()**) ?
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: To make sure I understand, you want to sum the values of each index correct? like `$sum = $a[0] + $b[0] + $c[0];`

Comment: Also, you say 'to a string', this is not clear. Do you mean 2 as a result cast as a String?

Comment: $stuff is an array containing those three arrays in it.
each of the arrays has a value (1 /  0.5 / 0.5)
I need those to be summarized to return a string (not array) result

Comment: Need a lot more info. Will the arrays be the same number of indexes each time? What should be done if 1 array has more indexes then the other 2? What if there are more than 3 arrays? Please clarify your question. Include the code you have attempted to use.

Comment: and you are right  -there could be more arrays to sum.
but this is pretty much it. I have an array received form DB (shown above) which values I'd liek to have combined to get the final sum
In this particular case: 1 + 0.5 + 0.5 = 2

Comment: Well you could tell the database to SUM them for you

Comment: Or `$sum = array_sum(array_column($stuff, 0));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for. Simple answer, iterate over your array of arrays. When you have completed the calculation, re-cast the variable to String if you like.

```
<?php
$stuff = array(
    array(1),
    array(0.5),
    array(0.5)
);

$result = 0;
foreach($stuff as $i){
    $result += $i[0];
}

$stringResult = strval($result);
echo is_string($stringResult) . " : " . $stringResult;
// 1 : 2
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Lord Twisty! I do appreciate your help